# Replace "advanced" pattern in sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I cant figure out how to change this:

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{pgf} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}\usepackage{times}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

to this using sed only

```
REPLACED
REPLACED REPLACEDREPLACEDREPLACED
REPLACED
```

Im trying stuff like `sed 's!\\.*\([.*]\)\?{.\+}!REPLACED!g' FILE`

but that gives me

```
REPLACED
REPLACED
REPLACED
```

I think .* gets used and everything else in my pattern is just ignored, but I can't figure out how to go about this.

After I learned how to format a regex like that, my next step would be to change it to this:

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

So I would appreciate any pointers in that direction too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that happens to work for the example you gave:

```
sed 's/\\[^\\[:space:]]\+/REPLACED/g'
```

I.e. match a backslash followed by one or more characters that are not whitespace or another backslash.

To make things more specific, you can use

```
sed 's/\\[[:alnum:]]\+\(\[[^][]*\]\)\?{[^{}]*}/REPLACED/g'
```

I.e. match a backslash followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by an optional `[ ]` group, followed by a `{ }` group.

The `[ ]` group matches `[`, followed by zero or more non-bracket characters, followed by `]`.

The `{ }` group matches `{`, followed by zero or more non-brace characters, followed by `}`.

Comment: @Peterhausen A good rule of thumb is to avoid `.*` because it's not specific enough. It can match everything, even things you didn't intend to match. Character classes are very useful here.

Comment: For the first script - `\+` is GNU sed only, you'd need `\{1,\}` to be POSIX compliant but `*` would work in all seds for this example. In the 2nd you'd need to use `\{0,1\}` instead of `\?` to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: So this helped me alot. But one last thing remains that I can't find a solution for. This matches `\ABC[xyz]{}` (stuff in the curley bracket is empty). How do I get smth to exclude the curley brackets and the empty string inse of the curley brackets. So above example would not match anymore, since it has an empty string inside of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue! It features the "frugal quantifiers":

```
perl -pe 's!\\.*?\.?{.+?}!REPLACED!g' FILE
```

Note that I removed the capturing group as you didn't use it anywhere. Also, `[.*]` matches either a dot or an asterisk, but you probably wanted to match a literal dot instead.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I am not allowed to use perl.